# Insert complex React components within a contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

My goal is to insert in a "contentEditable" div, complex reacts components (API calls to enrich the content, action buttons etc..). These components must be inserted anywhere in the text like a bullet point. It  would work a little like gmail does when you type an email address which becomes sort of an object once it is validated, except that in my case this object would have multiple fields within it.

So the best solution I found is to feed the contentEditable with a list containing either text or a component. For example:

```
<div contentEditable=true>
<span> Some text... blah blah blah </span>
<ComplexComponent />
  <span> Some more text</span>
<ComplexComponent />
</div>
```

So the rendering is really interesting, the components are well inserted in the middle of the text and the list of texts/components adjusts according to the user's actions.

Is there another architecture than this texts/components list?

I am sure you can imagine how cumbersome it is to manage all the user events to keep them under control.

**An anthology:**
Once rendered by React, the components in the middle of the text are considered as editable text; they would even be erasable in any way if we don't set up an algo to protect them.
For the same reason Chrome will not distinguish itself if you CtrlX on a selection that includes a React component, the structure becomes difficult to maintain ... unless special rules
You have to keep the style of your components... so what if the user selects a component from the text and puts it in bold? or even makes it a bulleted list? the DOM nodes break... unless you have a special rule again
A trick: I play with the keys of the texts or components to force their re-creation at the right time (I avoid the classic render so as not to reset the cursor each time a key is pressed...)
...and so on so forth...

**=> How to adopt a clear and maintainable code structure?**
I create functions as I go along to deal with the problems encountered, I put these functions in the functional component of my contentEditable, which is starting to grow....
In short, all this is a bit of a craft, especially with this list of texts/components.
However react doesn't particularly advocate a classic object architecture with its inheritances etc...

Anyone could get me out of this hole ?

Comment: In the end you're asking about a WYSIWYG editor that uses React components to represent internal editor state. I'd start by looking at React-based editors and see how they do their rendering--this is a non-trivial undertaking under the best of circumstances; I would build on existing work as much as possible.

Comment: I can only agree with you, this is very non-trivial 